# How to remove nan (float) item(s) from a list of mixed data types in python

Tags: python

I have a list with mixed data types:

```
Z = ['a','b', float('NaN'), 'd']
```

I would like to remove the nan observations.

I tried the following based on a couple of multiple suggestions but nothing worked:

```
Z = [x for x in Z if x != 'nan']
Z = [x for x in Z if x != float('NaN')]
```

Comment: math.isnan does not work for mixed data types

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nice hack is do `Z = [x for x in Z if x == x]`
This works since NaN is not equal to itself.

Comment: True, but better use `math.isnan`, it's made for that.

Comment: I get the error that x must be a real number not str with math.isnan

Comment: There are probably other cases when x is not equal to itself so I prefer to expliticly check for NaN

Comment: mixing several different types of data in one list often causes trouble. If you insist, you can check `type(x) == float` and only do your NaN test then.

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy

```
import numpy as np 

arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, np.nan, 8, 3, np.nan, 6])
print(arr)
>>>[ 0.  1.  2.  4. nan  8.  3. nan  6.]

arr = arr[np.where(~np.isnan(arr))]
print(arr)
>>>[0. 1. 2. 4. 8. 3. 6.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `math.isnan` to check for NaNs, like this:

```
Z = [x for x in Z if not math.isnan(x)]
```

Comment: This does not work for mixed data types (e.g. when x is a string)