# How to change the nth character of every string in a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have the following list of strings:

```
list = ['ABC.010120.01', 'ABC.010220.02', 'ABC.010220.03']
```

I want to change the 11th character of each string, meaning the 2nd '.', to a '-'.
I've tried:

```
list = [n[:10] + '-' + n[11:] for n in list]
```

However this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Well, you have a float somewhere in the list.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it works. Could you elaborate on where you are getting this error from?

Comment: The example you gave does not reproduce the issue you are having. Also, don't use `list` as a variable, you overwrite the builtin when you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a float somewhere in your list. You could use a for loop using `enumerate` and `str` to solve it:

```
lst = ['ABC.010120.01', 'ABC.010220.02', 'ABC.010220.03']
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    item = str(item)
    lst[index] = item[0:10] + "-" + item[11:]
```

Or, as a list comprehension:

```
new_lst = [item[0:10] + "-" + item[11:]
           for x in lst
           for item in [str(x)]]
```

Also, avoid calling your variables like builtin-objects (`list`, `dict` and the like).

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> a = ['ABC.010120.01', 'ABC.010220.02', 'ABC.010220.03']
>>> a = [n[:10] + '-' + n[11:] for n in a]
>>> a
['ABC.010120-01', 'ABC.010220-02', 'ABC.010220-03']
```

Note that `list`, as `str`, `set` and some others are word reserved for python3.

What you're doing it's like change the base of an `int`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are nan float values in the list. I found that following this solution linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820059/13144298) worked to remove the nan's from my list as so:

```
lst = ['ABC.010120.01', 'ABC.010220.02', 'ABC.010220.03', nan]
lst = [x for x in lst if x == x]
```

Executing that beforehand allows this line to function without error:

```
lst = [n[:10] + '-' + n[11:] for n in last]
```